# Tabbed or multi-stage form in vanilla PHP

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, validation, twitter-bootstrap-3

**Backstory**

I have a form on a page that is very long, it has around 20 to 30 fields. Currently, I am using the tab element of the Bootstrap framework to split the form across multiple tabs so that the overall experience is more digestible by the user.

This worked to some degree and I have a form across multiple tabs, with the tab at the end having a submit button.

**The problem**

When you get to the end of the form, if you've missed anything you need to know what you've missed, the issue is, as you're in a different tab how do you see the errors within the other tabs?

I tried the freely available Git Hub repository of Bootstrap Validator which is fine for single page forms but falls short for tabbed forms.

What is the best way to collect a series of errors and present them in the relevant tab, do I have the power to force the user back to a different tab to correct errors?

Or do I bite the bullet and just have a form that has multiple pages and stores data in the session?

Comment: _"do I have the power to force the user back"_ - Sure. You can do what ever you want. What is best is however another discussion, which is more opinion based and not as much a programming question as a UI/UX question. Start by deciding how you want it to work, make some attempts and if you run into some _specific_ issue with your actual (existing) code, please come back and we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

What about changing the type of element based on the page? If you could rewrite the URL to shoot them all to the same script, it might look like the example below.

This is probably a "first-pass" solution that a *Teach Yourself PHP* book would show before going on to something more sophisticated.

Pros:

- Easy to grasp

Cons:

- Breaks if you need images.
- Not the DRYest thing ever.
- You'll likely a tonne of logic in your view.

  - If you don't, it's because you're already great at abstracting problems like this, but then you've likely got a more sohpisticated approach.

Ex.:

```
<?php

$firstName = true === isset($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : '';

// If we're on page 1, show. If not, keep the data persistent in the HTML, but hide it.
<?php if ($page === 1) : ?>
    <input type="text" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>" />
<?php else : ?>
    <input type="hidden" name="first_name" value="<?php echo $firstName; ?>" />
<?php endif; ?>
```